I can’t buy sell or transfer any coin on eth using my coinbase wallet. Fails instantly , says failed to sign. Same wallets works on Base
I can’t buy sell or transfer any coin on eth chain using my coinbase wallet.  Fails instantly , says failed to sign.  Same wallets works on Base chain.  Have tried uniswap sushiswap MetaMask, sending, everything fails , never had this issue . High slippage low slippage

There can be nonce issue with wallet, though generally doesn't happen.
Next, gas fees might be high. Lastly, maybe public rpc was crowded. Try again if it still persists, please share more details
